# Permission denied config.inc.php

Tags: php, permissions, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install canvace, but both in local and on another dev server I'm getting error "file_put_contents(config.inc.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied" during installation.

I've found 3 config.inc.php in my server and changed their permission to 777 (one at the time), but i still get the same error.

Any hint on what should i try next?

Comment: the directory needs write permission. if the file is remove and added again setting the 777 on file doesn't matter.

Comment: Check permissions of the folders

Comment: put 777 on the 3 directories and the 3 files... but i still get the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file config.inc.php is not owned by root. You can use `ls -al` to see the user and group names in the directory the file is at. Try using CHOWN and changing the user/group to the PHP/web user and group.

Comment: i actually had that same problem the other day. :). It was owned by a different user/group and not the Web user that Apache uses. Once I changed ownership, it fixed the problem. The permissions were fine. BTW for a file the permissions should be 666 not 777. Also if the owner of the file is the one making the changes you can leave it at 644 for better security.

Comment: switched owner and group to www-data but still nothing... (thanks for the hint about permissions)

Comment: where is the file located relative to the other web files on the server?  Also depending on where the PHP file is that is executing the command, use the full path. `file_put_contents("/var/www/path/to/my/config.inc.php);` and see how that works too.

Comment: ok, so the config.inc.php file is created on configuration in the canvace/DevEnv (and has nothing to do with phpmyadmin's file of the same name) all i had to do was change owner and group of the DevEnv folder... thanks everybody